# How to subtract the old value with current value from database?

Tags: sql, vb.net, subtraction

my question is I have 2 tables. let say `Table Old` and `Table Current`. Both tables have columns `Quantity`. `Old.Quantity` is the old values, and `Current.Quantity` is the current values.

Table Old :

```
id  pro.no  Quantity
1    123        3
```

Table Current :

```
id  pro.no  Quantity
1    123       2
```

SQL :

```
SELECT A.`Quantity`, B.`Quantity`
FROM Table Current A 
LEFT JOIN Table Old B ON B.`pro.no` = A.`pro.no`
WHERE A.`id` = '1'
```

So, I want to subtract both values to get the new values which is `1` So that, when user key in the `pro.no` into the `textbox`, it'll show them they new value for `Quantity` is `1`.

I am using `VB.NET` for the backend, and I'm still new for this language too.

Comment: Simply `Old.Quantity-Current.Quantity`? By the way, using aliases like `A` and `B` don't help readability of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply subtract both columns, however as this is a left join you'll need to care for the null values:

```
SELECT CASE
      WHEN o.quantity IS NULL THEN c.quantity
      ELSE c.quantity - o.quantity
    END
  FROM current c LEFT JOIN old o ON ... WHERE ...
```

or alternatively

```
SELECT c.quantity - CASE WHEN o.quantity IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE o.quantity END
  FROM current c LEFT JOIN old o ON ... WHERE ...
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer! instead of subtract in sql, I do it at backend instead. and it works !